# How can I make bootstrap collapse accordion work with col-md-6 (multiple columns)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

The Bootstrap accordion collapse only works in the first column. How can I make it work in the second column as well?

**HTML** (First, working Bootstrap accordion),

```
<div class="picture-container">
<div class="pic-group-heading">Recreational</div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
   <div class="panel eagle">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
     ICE ARENA AND MORE POWERPOINT PRESENTATION
        </h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOnea" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOnea">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel eagle">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwoa">
      <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwoa" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwoa">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          RINK MAGAZINE ARTICLE
        </h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwoa" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwoa">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-img">
          <a href="#">
            <figure>
              <img src="http://www.eaglecoatings.net/content/supertherm/projectpictures/RinkMag/rinkcover.jpg" alt="" align="middle"/>
              <img src="http://www.eaglecoatings.net/content/supertherm/projectpictures/RinkMag/rink1.jpg" alt="" align="middle"/>
              <img src="http://www.eaglecoatings.net/content/supertherm/projectpictures/RinkMag/rink2.jpg" alt="" align="middle"/>
              <img src="http://www.eaglecoatings.net/content/supertherm/projectpictures/RinkMag/rink3.jpg" alt="" align="middle"/>
              <img src="http://www.eaglecoatings.net/content/supertherm/projectpictures/RinkMag/image003.jpg" alt="" align="middle"/>
            </figure>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

but when I add a second column the collapsing accordion effect stops working.

**HTML** (Second, not working accordion collapse)

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel eagle">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOnea" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOnea">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          ICE ARENA AND MORE POWERPOINT PRESENTATION
        </h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOnea" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOnea">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel eagle">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwoa">
      <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwoa" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwoa">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          RINK MAGAZINE ARTICLE
        </h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwoa" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwoa">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-img">
          <a href="#">
            <figure>
              <img src="http://www.eaglecoatings.net/content/supertherm/projectpictures/RinkMag/rinkcover.jpg" alt="" align="middle"/>
              <img src="http://www.eaglecoatings.net/content/supertherm/projectpictures/RinkMag/rink1.jpg" alt="" align="middle"/>
              <img src="http://www.eaglecoatings.net/content/supertherm/projectpictures/RinkMag/rink2.jpg" alt="" align="middle"/>
              <img src="http://www.eaglecoatings.net/content/supertherm/projectpictures/RinkMag/rink3.jpg" alt="" align="middle"/>
              <img src="http://www.eaglecoatings.net/content/supertherm/projectpictures/RinkMag/image003.jpg" alt="" align="middle"/>
            </figure>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```